# CodeIgniter Third party class not loading

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to implement Dashboard widget class (found here: http://harpanet.com/programming/php/codeigniter/dashboard/index#installation) but it is giving me error `Unable to load the requested class`

I have tried to add this class in autoload as well as menually to my controller `$this->load->library('dash')` but this also giving the same error.

I have checked `dash.php` and found below method `private function __example__()` but can't understand what the developer is saying in comment.

```
class Dash
{
    private function __example__()
    {
        /*
         * This function is purely to show an example of a dashboard method to place
         * within your own controller.
         */

        // load third_party hArpanet dashboard library
        $this->load->add_package_path(APPPATH.'third_party/hArpanet/hDash/');
        $dash =& $this->load->library('dash');
        $this->load->remove_package_path(APPPATH.'third_party/hArpanet/hDash/');

        // configure dashboard widgets - format: type, src, title, cols, alt (for images)
        $dash->widgets = array(

                    array('type'=>'oop',     'src'=>'test_dash',         'title'=>'Test OOP Widget',    'cols'=>3),

                    // if 'title' is set to FALSE, the title block is omitted entirely
                    // note: this is an 'html' widget but is being fed content from a local method
                    array('type'=>'html',     'src'=>self::test_method(), 'title'=>false,    'cols'=>3),

                    array('type'=>'file',     'src'=>'saf_inv.htm',         'title'=>'Safety Investigation'),

                    // multi-content widget - set widget title in outer array (also note use of CI anchor to create a link)
                    array('title'=>anchor('tz', 'TARGET ZERO'),
                            // sub-content follows same array format as single content widget
                            // 'img' content can also have an 'alt' text
                            array('type'=>'img',    'src'=>'saf_tzout.gif',      'alt'=>'Action Completed'),
                            array('type'=>'file',    'src'=>'saf_tz.htm'),
                            array('type'=>'file',    'src'=>'ave_close.htm',     'title'=>'Average Time to Close')
                            ),

                    array('type'=>'file',    'src'=>'saf_meet.htm',        'title'=>'Safety Meeting'),
                    array('type'=>'file',    'src'=>'saf_acc.htm',        'title'=>'Accident Investigation'),
                    array('type'=>'file',    'src'=>'saf_hazmat.htm',     'title'=>anchor('hazmat', 'HAZMAT')),
                    array('type'=>'file',    'src'=>'saf_cont.htm',         'title'=>'Loss of Containment'),
                    array('type'=>'file',    'src'=>'saf_worksinfo.htm',    'title'=>'Works Information'),

                    // an action widget - 'clear' will generate a blank widget with a style of clear:both
                    array('type'=>'clear'),

                    // multi-content widget - width can be set using the 'cols' param in outer array
                    array('title'=>'RAG Report', 'cols' => 2,

                            array('type'=>'file',    'src'=>'saf_rag.htm'),
                            array('type'=>'img',    'src'=>'ProcSaf.gif')),

                    array('type'=>'file',    'src'=>'saf_chrom.htm',        'title'=>'Chrome checks'),
                );

        // populate the view variable
        $widgets = $dash->build('safety');

        // render the dashboard
        $this->load->view('layout_default', $widgets);

    }
...................

} // end of Dash class
```

**Installation path is** `root/application/third_party/hArpanet/hDash/libraries/dash.php`

**How can I load this class to my system and use widgets?**

Comment: did you try library class name as `CI_Dash`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to create a library that initialize the third party class:

for Eg:

--in library create a file named **mydash.php** --

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MyDash
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once APPPATH.'third_party/hArpanet/hDash/libraries/dash.php';
    }
}
```

load the library using:

```
$this->load->library('mydash');
```

then you are able to use the Dash class. Also able to load library in autoload.

Thank you...

Comment: Yeah I have done the same way.. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry to hear you were having problems, (I've only just noticed this SO entry). Thanks to ReNiSh for his workaround, much appreciated.

You do **not** however need to use the library approach to implement the 'require_once' of hDash. I have now written a walkthrough for getting hDash installed and running, which you can find here: http://harpanet.com/programming/php/codeigniter/dashboard/walkthrough

Also, note that as of yesterday, 3rd Feb 2014, hDash has been updated to version 1.2.

Answer (score 2):

I am using PDF Parser from http://pdfparser.org/

I create files application/libraries/pdf.php

```
class Pdf
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        require_once APPPATH."/third_party/pdfparser.php";
    }
}
```

Then I create file application\third_party\pdfparser.php

```
if (!defined('pdfparser')) {
    define('pdfparser', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
    require(pdfparser . 'pdfparser/autoload.php');
}
```

Last, I include PDF Parser Library in Directory => application\third_party\pdfparser

Comment: Andy could you have a look at my question, regarding PDFParser and CodeIgniter ? I have tried your solution by getting trouble... http://stackoverflow.com/q/41238075/2278301